# R reassign values from a column depending on the frequency

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I'm tryng to get the column "names" from my dataframe, and change the names with lesser frequency to "others" in order to simplify a later Java program. For example:

```
someValue   Names
1           Ramon
2           Alex
4           Ramon
1           Luke
2           Han
3           Leia
4           Luke
8           Ramon
20          Luke
```

Now, the names with less than 3 frequency have to become others:

```
someValue   Names
1           Ramon
2           Others
4           Ramon
1           Luke
2           Others
3           Others
4           Luke
8           Ramon
20          Luke
```

And I am a little lost with this, I hope anyone knows a quick way to do this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `table` function to calculate the frequencies, and then find the ones whose frequencies are too low.
An example using character strings:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    someValue = 1:50,
    Names = sample(LETTERS, 50, TRUE),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
n.tab <- table( df$Names )
n.many <- names( n.tab[ n.tab > 3] )
df[ !(df$Names %in% n.many), "Names"] <- "Others"
df
```

Or the same example, but with a factor:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    someValue = 1:50,
    Names = sample(LETTERS, 50, TRUE)
)
n.tab <- table( df$Names )
n.many <- names( n.tab[ n.tab > 3] )

levels(df$Names)[ !(levels(df$Names) %in% n.many) ] <- "Others"
df
```

Comment: I'm testing it right now, thanks, i'll tel you the results

Comment: It gives me this warning:" In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = c("Otros", "Otros", "Otros",  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated"  and the names that fit, are assigned with NA

Comment: That's because you use factors, where I used a character string.  
In that case you could simply alter the factor levels: `levels(df$Names)[ !(levels(df$Names) %in% n.many) ] <- "Others"` (use this instead of my second last line.

Answer (score 1):

Following one-liner also works:

```
> ddf$Names = ifelse(ddf$someValue<3, 'Others', ddf$Names)
```

or:

```
> ddf$Names = with(ddf, ifelse(someValue<3, 'Others', Names))

> ddf
  someValue  Names
1         1 Others
2         2 Others
3         4  Ramon
4         1 Others
5         2 Others
6         3   Leia
7         4   Luke
8         8  Ramon
9        20   Luke
```

Just make sure that the Names column is 'character' and not 'factor'. If factor, it can be changed with as.character(ddf$Names).